# html5 localstorage accessiblity

Tags: html, web-storage

In html5 if I create an new local storage key called *mykey* from a website *www.a.com*, will I be able to access *mykey* from another site, say *www.b.com* ?
                                                     Can any website access the key/value pairs created by other website? Please explain in detail. Even links will do fine.
I created two jsp files both of them using the same local storage and deployed them in jboss as different files. Now both the domains i.e localhost:8080/store1/local_storage.jsp and localhost:8080/store2/local_storage1.jsp are able to access the same key/value pair. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Just like cookies are these objects only accessible from the domain that created them, for security reasons.

If you want to pass data from one domain to another I can recommend a form that posts to another site or put the data in a query string :)

Comment: I created two jsp files both of them using the same local storage and deployed them in jboss as different files. Now both the domains i.e http://localhost:8080/store1/local_storage.jsp and http://localhost:8080/store2/local_storage1.jsp are able to access the same key/value pair.

Comment: Ofc, the domain is localhost for both

Comment: I know the feeling when you stare blind on a problem ;)